# The "is-active" class is added to the main-menu links only when the site is accessed by an anonymous user

Tags: navigation, 9

I use this simple template (menu--main.html.twig) to render the main menu I created.

```
<ul>
    {% for item in items %}
    <li>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below is not empty %}
            <div class='submenu'>
                {% for subitem in item.below %}
                    {{ link(subitem.title, subitem.url) }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Drupal is nice enough to add an *is-active* class to the currently active link, which is good and worked fine for a bit.

Recently, it stopped working properly and I have no idea why. Currently it is only applying an *is-active* class to the menu links when I am not logged in. When I log in, there is only a menu link that gets that class applied to it when active.

The menu links are identical, apart title and destination on the *Edit Menu Link* menu, so I'm very confused.

Can anybody offer suggestions for things to try to help solve this problem?

Comment: `is-active` is not rendered server-side in your Twig template, but added client-side with JavaScript. If it stopped working then you quite likely have javascript errors on your site.

Comment: Thank you, as the site is not JavaScript heavy I didn't think to look into that but it turns out that was indeed the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with JavaScript, at some point I overwrote the `html.html.twig` template in order to add a container div immediately after the body tag, which subsequently wrapped this line:

```html
<js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token }}">
```

Moving this one line outside of my container div but still within the body tag fixed the issue.

This article was useful https://createdbycocoon.com/knowledge/drupal-8-js-errors-cannot-read-property-currentpath-undefined